# What does a sequence being a Bessel sequence but not a frame mean?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, frame-theory

A sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in I}$ is a frame for a separable Hilbert space $H$ if there exists $0<A\leq B<\infty$ such that 
$$ A\|f\|^{2} \leq \sum_{n\in I}|\langle f,f_{n}\rangle|^{2}\leq B\|f\|^{2}$$
for all $f\in H$. If the sequence only satisfying the upper bound it is called a Bessel sequence.

Now my questin is: if a given sequence is Bessel sequence but not a frame, what does this mean?

My guess is that: there exists (a non-zero) $f\in H$ such that
$$ A\|f\|^{2} > \sum_{n\in I}|\langle f,f_{n}\rangle|^{2} $$
for all $A$.

But I'm not sure if this is correct! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange kim! You almost had it, but your logical ordering is incorrect. Currently it says : There exists a single non-zero $f$ such that blah blah holds for all A,B, while the actual negation would be: Choose any A,B. Then there exists a non-zero $f$ such that blah blah... (EDIT: You updated your question a bit, but I think you will still see my point.)

Comment: Ok, so $f$ will depends on $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: Yes.      $      $ $       $        $         $

Comment: So, if this is the case, then we have: given $A_{m}>0$, we can find $g_{m}\in H$ such that $$A_{m}\|g_{m}\|^{2}> \sum_{n\in I}|\langle f,g_{m}\rangle|^{2}.$$  What we can say about those functions $g_{m}$, for example, (1) Is the sequence $g_{m}$ converges in $H$? Or,(2) Is $ |\langle f,g_{m}\rangle|$  bounded above? Or,(3) Is $ \sup_{m}\|g_{m}\|$ exists?

Comment: You should make a new thread for your new questions, or edit this question in the main post. They will receive more attention if you make a new question.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246655/173147

Answer (score 2):

> if a given sequence is Bessel sequence but not a frame, what does this mean?

It means that for every $A>0$ there exists $f\in H$ such that $$A\|f\|^{2} > \sum_{n\in I}|\langle f,f_{n}\rangle|^{2} $$

> What we can say about those functions $g_m$, for example, (1) Is the sequence $g_m$ converges in $H$? Or (2) Is $|\langle f,g_m\rangle|$ bounded above? Or (3) Is $\sup_m \|g_m\|$ exists?

None of  (1), (2), (3) hold generally. For example, if the subspace $V=\{f_n\}^\perp$ is nontrivial, the vectors $g_m$ can be arbitrary vectors from $V$.