# Does a Bessel sequence not being a frame mean that $\sum_n|\langle f,f_n\rangle|^2>B\|f\|^2$ for some $f\in H$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, frame-theory

I'm posting this question again because I'm still confused about the answer!

A sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in I}$ is called a Bessel sequence in a Hilbert space $H$, if there exists $B>0$ such that 
$$\sum_{n\in I}|\langle f,f_{n}\rangle|^{2}\leq B\|f\|^{2}$$
for all $f\in H$.

Now my questin is: if a given sequence is not Bessel sequence, does it mean that

given $B>0$, there exists (a non-zero) $f\in H$ such that
$$ \sum_{n\in I}|\langle f,f_{n}\rangle|^{2}> B\|f\|^{2}$$

Thanks!

(old post: [If a sequence is not a frame](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152956/if-a-sequence-is-not-a-frame))

Comment: This is the negation that $\{f_{n}\}_n$ is a Bessel sequence and  the negation do not make sense if $f=0$ because both sides are zero.

Comment: So just to be sure: if we pick another $B$ we would find another $f\in H$ satisfying the second relation, and so forth, right!

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $\{f_n\}$ is not a Bessel sequence if for all integer $N$, we can find $g_N\in  H$ such that for all integer $N$, $$\sum_{n\in I}|\langle g_N,f_n\rangle|^2> N \lVert g_N\rVert^2,$$
exactly what you mean.